# str_replace is replacing only the first variable in an array in php

Tags: php

I am trying to replace a variable between {{}}, but it is only replacing the first variable.

My Code:

```
$array_content[]=array("USER_NAME", "John");  
$array_content[]=array("LOGIN_LINK", 'http://exampl.com/signin');
$array_content[]=array("SITE_NAME", 'Google');

$content = "Welcome to {{SITE_NAME}}, Hi, {{USER_NAME}}, now you can login here: {{LOGIN_LINK}}";
    
foreach ($array_content as $key=>$value){
    $mailcontent = str_replace("{{$value[0]}}", $value[1],$content);
}
$mailcontent = stripslashes($mailcontent);

echo $mailcontent;
```

Result:

Welcome to {Google}, Hi, {{USER_NAME}}, We want to tell thanks for the registration, now you can login here: {{LOGIN_LINK}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are moving the result of the `str_replace()` into a new variable inside the loop and therefore losing changes.

```
$array_content[]=array("USER_NAME", "John");  
$array_content[]=array("LOGIN_LINK", 'http://exampl.com/signin');
$array_content[]=array("SITE_NAME", 'Google');

$content = "Welcome to {{SITE_NAME}}, Hi, {{USER_NAME}}, now you can login here: {{LOGIN_LINK}}";
    
foreach ($array_content as $key=>$value){
    $content = str_replace("{{" . $value[0] . "}}", $value[1],$content);
    //^^^ changed here and  ^^                 ^^
}
$mailcontent = stripslashes($content);
```

You could also do this instead as str_replace() accepts arrays for param 1 and 2

```
$array_content = array("{{USER_NAME}}"=> "John", 
                       "{{LOGIN_LINK}}"=> 'http://exampl.com/signin', 
                       "{{SITE_NAME}}"=> 'Google');

$find = array_keys($array_content);
$replace = array_values($array_content);

$content = "Welcome to {{SITE_NAME}}, Hi, {{USER_NAME}}, now you can login here: {{LOGIN_LINK}}";

$mailcontent = str_replace($find, $replace,$content);

echo $mailcontent;
```

Comment: I haven't realized that, but now it's just replacing a brace {{SITE_NAME}} to {Google}

Comment: Changed the first param of str_replace()

Answer (score 3):

There are two problems here:

1. You are reusing the `$content` variable, over and over in your [**`str_replace()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), while you not saving the results.  If you define `$mailcontent` to be your `$content`, then you can just use `str_replace()` with `$mailcontent` as the subject and `$mailcontent` being the variable receiving the new value.
2. `{}` braces are used to encapsulate variable names in string interpolation, so, I updated the code to use simply concated strings.  (Source: [**PHP.net: Strings**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), see the section with *"Use {$ to get a literal {$. Some examples to make it clear..."*)

[**Full Working Demo.**](https://ideone.com/doHQhV)

```
$array_content[]=array("USER_NAME", "John");  
$array_content[]=array("LOGIN_LINK", 'http://exampl.com/signin');
$array_content[]=array("SITE_NAME", 'Google');

$content = "Welcome to {{SITE_NAME}}, Hi, {{USER_NAME}}, now you can login here: {{LOGIN_LINK}}";
    
$mailcontent = $content;
foreach ($array_content as $key=>$value){
    $mailcontent = str_replace('{{' . $value[0] . '}}', $value[1],$mailcontent );
}
$mailcontent = stripslashes($mailcontent);

echo $mailcontent;
```

Answer (score 2):

In double-quoted strings, the `{}` can be used to parse variables.  See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

You probably want to do:

```
str_replace('{{' . $value[0] . '}}', $value[1], $content);
```

Also, in your loop you are *overwriting* the value of `$mailcontent` each loop.  So, only the last variable will be replaced.  You want something like:

```
$mailcontent = $content;
foreach ($array_content as $key=>$value){
    $mailcontent = str_replace('{{' . $value[0] . '}}', $value[1], $mailcontent);
}
```